# Use an ansible fact in an if conditional - Jinja template

Tags: python, linux, ansible, jinja2, ansible-template

At the moment I have something like the following in my Ansible Jinja Template

```
{% for key in filebeat.values() %}
{% for x in key.servers %}
{% if x in {{ ansible_hostname }} %}
text-goes-here
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

When executing the ansible playbook, the following error is showing:

**AnsibleError: template error while templating string: expected token ':', got '}**

It seems that with Jinja, I cannot make use of **{{** ansible_hostname **}}** inside an if statement.

Is there some way that I can still get the value of ansible_hostname inside the if statement  to get around this issue? I have tried using lookup and other combinations but no luck so far.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never nest Jinja `{{...}}` template markers. If you're already inside a template context, you can just refer to variables by name...

```
{% if x in ansible_hostname %}
text-goes-here
{% endif %}
```

You're already using exactly the correct syntax in your `{% for ... %}` loops. You wrote:

```
{% for key in filebeat.values() %}
```

Instead of:

```
{% for key in {{ filebeat.values() }} %}
```

The `{% if ... %}` statement is no different.

Comment: This approach does seem to work if I define ansible_hostname with a static value in my vars.yaml file. My idea was to get the dynamic value of ansible_hostname that is provided via Ansible facts. When I try with {% if x in ansible_hostname %} without ansible_hostname being defined in vars.yaml, it does not work.

Comment: Thank you, managed to get it working with your suggested approach.